# Как подключить фастапи приложение к бд постгресс в докере?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi

уже третий день не могу решить проблему. Я написал fastapi приложение и решил запихнуть его в контейнер для удобства деплоя. Там же (в контейнере) я развернул бд Postgres, но приложение Fastapi не может подключиться к бд, уже не знаю что делать, перерыл весь интернет.

Докер-композ:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    ports: 
     - "5438:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
    image: postgres:13.9-alpine3.17

  fastapi:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    expose:
      - 8000

  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.8-alpine
    depends_on:
      - fastapi
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Файл окружения с подключением:

```
database-connect-addres = postgresql://admin:root@localhost:5438
```

Докер:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Ошибка:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5438 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5438 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
postgresql://admin:root@db:5432
```

У контейнера свой отдельный локалхост. Да и не мучай хост систему лишними пробросами. Подключайся напрямую и убери пробросы 8000 и 5458

Answer (score 0):

Удалось ли решить вопрос?
Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Мне помогло следующее:

1. Удалить базу данных, установленную локально в систему (освободить порт 5432), порты заменить на "**5432**:5432"
2. В адресе подключения к базе данных исправить localhost на название контейнера: postgresql://admin:root@**db**:**5432**